# Show banner and menu navigation bar on all pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Rails. I am using Aptana Studio 3 to write a small application.

In the Views folder, I added a new .html.erb page and added a jQuery navigation menu bar. This page also has a banner. I want to keep this as a base page (like Master Page in .NET) for all the other pages.

I want all the other pages to automatically show the banner and menu bar on top.

How to do this? I am using Rails 3.2.

**Edited**

Code of application.html.erb:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

      <script type="text/javascript" src="..\Libraries\jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('li.headlink').hover(
                        function() { $('ul', this).css('display', 'block'); },
                        function() { $('ul', this).css('display', 'none'); });
                });   
      </script>
      <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
            /* General */
            #cssdropdown, #cssdropdown ul { list-style: none; }
            #cssdropdown, #cssdropdown * { padding: 0; margin: 0; }

            /* Head links */
            #cssdropdown li.headlink { width: 220px; float: left; margin-left: -1px; border: 1px black solid; background-color: #e9e9e9; text-align: center; }
            #cssdropdown li.headlink a { display: block; padding: 15px; }

            /* Child lists and links */
            #cssdropdown li.headlink ul { display: none; border-top: 1px black solid; text-align: left; }
            #cssdropdown li.headlink:hover ul { display: block; }
            #cssdropdown li.headlink ul li a { padding: 5px; height: 17px; }
            #cssdropdown li.headlink ul li a:hover { background-color: LightBlue; color:Black }

            /* Pretty styling */
            body { font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; font-size: 0.8em;}
            #cssdropdown a { color: white; } #cssdropdown ul li a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
            #cssdropdown li.headlink { background-color: Blue;}
            #cssdropdown li.headlink ul { background-position: bottom; padding-bottom: 10px; }
      </style>  
</head>
<body>
<%= yield %>

        <div id="divMain">
            <div id="divHeader">
                <img src="..\Images\W.png">                 
            </div>
            <div id="divMenu">
                <ul id="cssdropdown">
                <li class="headlink">
                    <a href="#">Task</a>
                     <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Add New</a></li>
                     </ul>
                     </li>
                      <li class="headlink">
                      <a href="#">Reports</a>    
                         <ul>
                      <li><a href="#">Report</a></li>
                     </ul>
                 </li>
                </ul>               
            </div>
        </div>

<div id="content"><%= content_for?(:content) ? yield(:content) : yield %></div>         
</body>
</html>
```

Code of Content.html.erb

```
<% content_for :stylesheets do %>
  <div id="divLogin">

  </div>
<% end %>

<% content_for :MainContent do %>
  <div id="divMain">

  </div>
<% end %>

<%= render :partial  => "layouts\application.html.erb" %>
```

Answer (score 3):

Rails uses layouts as master templates. As default will you have one master layout template called `application`, which you can find in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`. If you look at this file will you see something like:

```
 # app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
 <html>
   <head>
     ...
   </head>
   <body>
     ...
     <div id="content">
       # Your page content will be inserted here:
       <%= yield %>
     </div>
     ...
   </body>
 </html>
```

As default will this be rendered for all pages, and the content of each page (fx your `new.html.erb`) would be rendered in the `yield` block.

This means that `application.html.erb` is the right place to but generel layout stuff, like menus and banners that should appear on all pages.

If you want to have something that varies a bit for each page (fx different banners) can you add a special `<%= yield(:banner) if content_for?(:banner) %>` in your `application.html.erb` file. You will then be able to add a block in each of your pages for a banner like this:

```
# app/views/some_resource/some_page.html.erb
<% content_for(:banner) do %>
  # insert page specifik banner here
<% end %>
# normal content for page
...
```

I hope this answers your question?

You can also read more about layouts (fx how to use more then one layout) on http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html

### Edit: correct way to implement `content.html.erb`

The content of `content.html.erb` should be:

```
# What is this? This has nothing to do with stylesheets?
<% content_for :stylesheets do %>
  <div id="divLogin">

  </div>
<% end %>

<div id="divMain">

</div>
```

So no `content_for :MainContent` block and don't render the ´application.html.erb´ layout template (it's not even a partial, so you can't do this).

Comment: My application.html.erb contains jQuery menu code as shown in my original post. In the content page it is not visible. I have updated the content page code that I am using. Please see edited original post. What changes are needed in my content page code?

Comment: First of all, you should not have inline javascript if you can avoid it! Extract it to a js file in your ´app/assets/javascripts´ directory. The same applies to css. 

Secondly you can't have a `content_for :stylesheets` if you don't have a associated `yield(:stylesheets)` in your `application.html.erb` file. The same applies to `content_for :MainContent`. Rails puts the whole page (all of `content.html.erb`) into the `yield` (without arguments) block in `application.html.erb` file, so there is no need to wrap it in a MainContent block.

Comment: I tried all your suggestions still it is not working. When I directly open the content page, it is neither showing the banner nor the menu. I also want to know whether I want to include any Render line to tell content page from where the layout is to be rendered?

Comment: The layout is defaulted to `application.html.erb`. You can change it in your controller, either by calling `layout "another_layout"` in the top, and this will work for all actions in the controller. Or you can call `render "some_action", :layout => "another_layout"` in a action, to change the layout for that action alone.

Comment: Are you coming somewhere whit this? Otherwise could we start a chat and i could help you out :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested layouts as described [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-nested-layouts).

Comment: So do I need to move this banner and menu bar to application.html.erb?

Comment: If you would like to have the banner and menu in the 'Master Page', then yes.

Comment: All the content pages will also go in the Layout folder?

Comment: I guess, I don't know what you're exactly trying to do: If you want the whole application to use the banner and the menu, then yes, put it in the application and let the other templates extend from that application page. If you want only a part of your app to have the menu, put it in a seperate html.erb file and let the pages you want to have the menu and the banner extend that file. It's quite flexible!

Comment: Ok I have moved the Banner and the Menu to the application.html.erb file. I am seeing the link you sent, but not following how to define content area in other page and access the banner and menu in the application.html.erb.

Comment: Please see the code above. What changes are needed in the content page.

Comment: You only need this in the content file:
        `<% content_for :content do %>
          <div id="divMain"></div>
          <%= content_for?(:news_content) ? yield(:news_content) : yield %>
        <% end %>
        <%= render :template => 'layouts/application' %>`

Comment: Nothing visible. Do I need HTML and Body tag in content page?

Comment: Nope, only the content you want that page to have.

Comment: I changed the content page code still I am not able to see any menu when content page is loaded. Please see the edited code in original post.

Answer (score 0):

Watch from 5:18,
from what I've read I think thats kind of what you may be looking for.
Hope it helps.

[Railscast #328](http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics)

Also here is a link to Twitter's bootstrap navbar which you may want to look into. It will show a banner and navigation bar on all pages and is fairly easy to set up.

http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

Answer (score -1):

One of the best sources for this topic is the beginning of the book The Rails View.  Here is the link: [The Rails View](http://pragprog.com/book/warv/the-rails-view)

This really helps with the `content_for` helper method, which will become your friend instantly once you know how to use it.